# Ubuntu 20.04 - python issue: numpy.linalg.norm() / Matplotlib plot cannot finish execution some code, never returns

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I ran into an odd problem with python on Ubuntu recently. My python environment runs fine, except that I cannot execute some basic `numpy` and `matplotlib` functions...

Whenever I tried `np.linalg.norm(x, ord=2)`, `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()`, or `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`, code execution gets stuck at that line and never progresses further, while thread CPU usage hits 100%... Examples below.

I tried this on a few different Anaconda environments running **different** versions python (3.9, 3.8, 3.7), a **fresh** Anaconda installation, and with Ubuntu's default Python, all ran into the same problems.

Also because this is happening different libraries, `numpy` and `matplotlib`, it makes me think that it might be related to something more fundamental, perhaps related to the Ubuntu OS libraries? **Unfortunately, I don't know when exactly this issue started happening, whether it was after some Ubuntu update or python package updates...***

Would any expert here happen to know what could be causing this issue? I'm trying to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu here...

Thank you.

## System Info

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Linux 5.11.0-40-generic x86_64

NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.00    Driver Version: 470.82.00    CUDA Version: 11.4

2x NVIDIA Geforece 1080Ti

Tried `python` versions / Anaconda environments:

- Anaconda `python`: `3.9.7`, `3.8.12`, `3.7.11`
- Ubuntu default python

Library versions:

- `numpy` `1.21.2`
- `matplotlib` `3.5.0` and `3.4.3`
- `ipykernel 6.5.0`
- `notebook 6.4.6`

## Numpy

With `numpy`, I noticed that I can run `np.linalg.norm()` with orders other than 2, but once I set `ord=2`, the code never finishes running, with CPU hits 100% for this thread.

I tried this in terminal with `python` and `jupyter notebook`, same problem...

```
import numpy as np

z = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)

print(np.linalg.norm(z, 1, axis=1))
print(np.linalg.norm(z, np.inf, axis=1))

# code stuck here... doesn't return....
# CPU running at 100% for this thread

print(np.linalg.norm(z, ord=2))
```

[image]

## Matplotlib

I ran into the same issue with `matplotlib` - when I call `plt.plot()` or `plt.subplots()`:

[image]

I also tried to run this in a python script, ran into the same problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as M
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200)
y = np.sin(x)

print(f"backend = {M.get_backend()}") # TkAgg

print('create figure...')
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # code execution will be stuck here...

print('calling plot now...')
ax.plot(x, y)
print('calling show()...')
plt.show()
```

Comment: both scripts work correctly and fast for me on `Python 3.8`, `Linux Mint 20` (based on `Ubuntu 20.04`. But it shows `Qt5Agg` instead of `TkAgg`

Comment: both runs fine on my 20.04 system, Python 3.8.8, numpy 1.21.2, matplotlib 3.5.0, jupyter 6.3.0

Comment: Try `conda update --all` for the appropriate environment, and then see what happens

Comment: @furas, Quang Hoang, thx, just tried Qt5Agg on my end, ran into the same problem... which MKL version are you guys using?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney well, I created new environments for it, still got the same problem, which makes me thing it's something more related to my linux installation.... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: Thx for chipping in still